# float values division in C

Tags: c, floating-point

The end result of my program yields the following values in two double variables declared as e1 and energy:

```
e1 = 278872475.434922
energy = 2982053.000000
```

my final result is per=e1 divided by energy.The actual answer is 93.5169.However,this when done in C through the following: per=e1/energy gives a completely different answer? What is the problem?

Comment: So, what answer *do* you get?

Comment: Can you show the actual code, including variable declarations?

Comment: Can you show us your actual code?

Comment: Question is not answerable in its current form. Please elaborate and/or show some code.

Answer (score 5):

### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double e1 = 278872475.434922;
    double energy = 2982053.000000;
    double per = e1 / energy;
    printf("%lf\n", per);
}
```

### Result

`93.516941`

Comment: Using floats yields 93.516945 - not much different.